# Is there gender separation for tourists who aren't praying at the Kotel (Western Wall)?

Tags: kotel-western-wall

I’m going with my wife and I’m not sure whether we will be separated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **upper** Kotel plaza is **not** separated by gender, and couples can stay together there; whether they choose to pray there, or not.

However the **lower** Kotel plaza (closer to the Wall), operates like a Traditional synagogue, which is gender separated; the right side being designated for women, and the left side being designated for men.

Comment: So we won’t be able to touch it together?

Comment: @user354948 You can try standing near the dividing partition, and you will be very close to each other.

Comment: Thanks. I’m trying to find labelled pictures for the different sections. Any links you can recommend?

Comment: @user354948 https://thekotel.org/en/western-wall/western-wall-cameras/ and https://thekotel.org/en/western-wall/cameras-prayer-plaza/. Also: https://makotrav.com/kotel-webcam-jerusalem/

Comment: In the first link, I see the male area to the left and the female area to the right, correct? So where would the unisex area be?

Comment: @user354948 The plaza consists of two different levels. The area in the foreground is higher, and is not segregated. It's only when you go to the lower level, is the plaza split in two.

Comment: Thank you. I can’t find a picture of the upper plaza anywhere… or I’m seeing it but not recognising it for what it is…

Comment: @user354948 I think that it's the latter. The area you're seeing in the foreground, is what I call the upper plaza.